# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 and ADFS randomly generates an error

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have configured WSO2IS 5.0.0 as an SAML 2.0 Identity Provider for my Service Provider application. I have also added and configured an ADFS 2.0 Identity Provider using the federated authenticator "SAML2 Web SSO Configuration". Access to the Service Provider application is protected using the ADFS Identity Provider. Everything is "randomly" working well, the user access the Service Provider being redirected to the WSO2 IS server who redirects the user to the ADFS server. After properly authenticated the user is redirected back to the WSO2 server and given access to the Service Provider.

My problem is that the ADFS server "randomly" returns the error "MSIS7000: The sign in request is not compliant to the WS-Federation language for web browser clients or the SAML 2.0 protocol WebSSO profile." when receiving the authn request generated by WSO2IS. I have compared the authn request when working and when not working but have not been able to detect any significant differences. I have never experieced this problem using the same ADFS server before.

I have also a working setup where the Service Provider use the same ADFS server directly without receiving any errors. The same setup with the Service Provider application and WSO2 IS is also working with another third-party SAML 2.0 Identity Provider.

Anyone who has experienced the same problem with ADFS and has a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

We don't used ADFS but our own IDP.
And we have also issues setting up SAML Federation.

It looks like WSO2 SAML Federation is sending a GET instead of a POST.

We have change't our IDP to allow GET. But this is not in the specs!!!